# Creating dynamic DIV breaks JQuery-UI Droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a draggable element and a div with two static drop zones:

```
<img id="dragimage"  src="_images/image.png"  >

<div class="lines">
    <div class="dropzone" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black">this is a dropzone</div>
    <div class="dropzone" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black">this is a dropzone</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function  () {
        $("#dragimage").draggable();

        $(".dropzone").droppable({
            drop: function(event,ui){
                alert('dropped');
            }
    });
</script>
```

I have a button that dynamically adds additional drop zones.  I add the "ui-droppable" class to the dynamic drop zones since calling .droppable() adds that class automatically to any static droppable elements.

```
function AddLine()
{
    var linecount = $("#linecount").val();
    var linediv = $(".lines").html();

    linecount++;
    $("#linecount").val(linecount);
    linediv += '<div  class="dropzone ui-droppable " style="height:75px;width:100%;border:1px solid black">New Drop Zone ' + linecount + '</div>';
    $(".lines").html(linediv);
}
```

When I drop the draggable element into one of the static drop zones prior to adding any dynamic drop zones, I get the alert every time with no difficulties.

When I add one or more dynamic drop zones, the drop event never fires again, even for the original static drop zones.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061339/jquery-ui-droppable-on-dynamically-added-element)

The AddLine method above is now this:

```
function AddLine()
{
    var linecount = $("#linecount").val();
    var linediv = $(".lines").html();

    linecount++;

    $("#linecount").val(linecount);

    var newline = $('<div  class="dropzone ui-droppable" class="ui-droppable" style="height:75px;width:100%;border:1px solid black">New Drop Zone ' + linecount + '</div>').appendTo(".lines");

    newline.droppable(      {
        drop: function(event,ui)
        {
            alert('dropped'+linecount);
        }
    });

}
```